# trying to get property of non object curl issue

Tags: php

I have a curl setup as follows to access a json object

`$ch = curl_init();`

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://sitename.com");

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookiefilename.txt');


 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host:sitename.com'));

 $output = curl_exec($ch);

 curl_close($ch);
 $output = json_decode($output);
 echo $output->property;
```

I get the error 'trying to access property of non object'.

Answer (score 1):

The only time you are trying to access a property of an object, is here:

```
echo $output->property;
```

So do a `var_dump($output)` to see what is happening before and after the previous line:

```
var_dump($output)
$output = json_decode($output);
var_dump($output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what you've tried or looked into.

The most likely thing would seem to be that the site isn't returning valid JSON, and so `json_decode` is returning `NULL`.

Alternately, perhaps what's being returned is valid JSON, but not an object (e.g., `true` or `false`, although at the top level a JSON package should always be an object or an array).